# Why is the curl request going through but nothing is showing up on the server side?

Tags: curl, github-actions

I'm using this api command in a github action:

```
curl -X POST https://panel.wumpus.host/api/client/servers/d7704dee/command -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: ***" -d "\{ 'command': 'npm run dev' \}"
```

It doesn't fail but no command is outputted in my server's terminal. The weird thing is when I run it on this website it works?
https://reqbin.com/curl

It seems from the error below it reloaded a few times and struggled with not being a javascript browser? Any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Just a moment...</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    body {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; font-family:-apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, "Helvetica Neue",Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.7em;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
    h1 { text-align: center; font-weight:700; margin: 16px 0; font-size: 32px; color:#000000; line-height: 1.25;}
    p {font-size: 20px; font-weight: 400; margin: 8px 0;}
    p, .attribution, {text-align: center;}
    #spinner {margin: 0 auto 30px auto; display: block;}
    .attribution {margin-top: 32px;}
    @keyframes fader     { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
    @-webkit-keyframes fader { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles { animation: fader 1.6s infinite;}
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: .2s;}
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: .4s;}
    .bubbles { background-color: #f58220; width:20px; height: 20px; margin:2px; border-radius:100%; display:inline-block; }
    a { color: #2c7cb0; text-decoration: none; -moz-transition: color 0.15s ease; -o-transition: color 0.15s ease; -webkit-transition: color 0.15s ease; transition: color 0.15s ease; }
    a:hover{color: #f4a15d}
    .attribution{font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5;}
    .ray_id{display: block; margin-top: 8px;}
    #cf-wrapper #challenge-form { padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px; }
    #cf-hcaptcha-container { text-align:center;}
    #cf-hcaptcha-container iframe { display: inline-block;}
  </style>

      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="35">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(){
      
      window._cf_chl_opt={
        cvId: "2",
        cType: "non-interactive",
        cNounce: "91338",
        cRay: "6bc41476ff666841",
        cHash: "bba365f00dd882d",
        cPMDTk: "HtOA0Rmh1RAHduAh85.229oLoXdpgbFkzc36VMqYnes-1639281985-0-gaNycGzNBj0",
        cFPWv: "b",
        cTTimeMs: "1000",
        cRq: {
          ru: "aHR0cHM6Ly9wYW5lbC53dW1wdXMuaG9zdC9hcGkvY2xpZW50L3NlcnZlcnMvZDc3MDRkZWUvY29tbWFuZA==",
          ra: "Y3VybC83LjU1LjE=",
          rm: "UE9TVA==",
          d: "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",
          t: "MTYzOTI4MTk4NS4xMTYwMDA=",
          m: "hxWXOZnkfpk7U1u6CFZUPF8PmnxQsQ2Bdxosrc2IbgY=",
          i1: "Rdr3GIPtCN/up3lbEL8dPw==",
          i2: "bri5Lzug/f1M+2F9aDlw1A==",
          zh: "5GYX6ZGMqv/pAZUgd1TEEUWL0BVbzm2po2OjZa23aS4=",
          uh: "yJo4Yz2g40fRnUbkl+3xumbT2Zvi1Q9/8tEG1FzQ5ro=",
          hh: "NT/OxIuLXGhtN0PfvmV4Zn62AkqhDfIGrrwLAgnxR0k=",
        }
      }
      window._cf_chl_enter = function(){window._cf_chl_opt.p=1};
      
    })();
    //]]>
  </script>
  

</head>
<body>
  <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="20">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
          <div class="cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack">
  <noscript>
    <h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>
  </noscript>
  <div id="cf-content" style="display:none">
    
    <div id="cf-bubbles">
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
    </div>
    <h1><span data-translate="checking_browser">Checking your browser before accessing</span> panel.wumpus.host.</h1>
    
    <div id="no-cookie-warning" class="cookie-warning" data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="display:none">
      <p data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="color:#bd2426;">Please enable Cookies and reload the page.</p>
    </div>
    <p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>
    <p data-translate="allow_5_secs" id="cf-spinner-allow-5-secs" >Please allow up to 5 seconds&hellip;</p>
    <p data-translate="redirecting" id="cf-spinner-redirecting" style="display:none">Redirecting&hellip;</p>
  </div>
   
  <form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/api/client/servers/d7704dee/command?__cf_chl_f_tk=HtOA0Rmh1RAHduAh85.229oLoXdpgbFkzc36VMqYnes-1639281985-0-gaNycGzNBj0" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="md" value="uVDbN7RHLFH_WoSMXoUBiegAWT339l5zWuR_PX7lJpk-1639281985-0-AWInff16Xh7-NJEGlgGQ1ehX3u_L-SNOnBzq681K8e7SPWEDlu7QKwd_LSAzIyat_uRFv7tIJXVgIWt4vMouDbj2bJtst7UPbHgOgWYnHEPUBVsq53GbOmnIcR0kQeYD4-jAsgYuQIH2rat10MWI9FFSFRqyTo3T9H-19EThInYc6BCW_HzOHe3i2aEKU6JpPudgU96PuXb-DpkdSZuZ-S7J2cBp59Ajnx645PAeO_lIPraS8W5NW25SzSqzcwMyOwY26vpx5PjlFs7BA4bSQ7ZUEfvYfvy7Pw6fTyIFq_LC2XSxZxaN5ZDXKKDcABmD1sTevDFFEwcxuW_4S9imosguf07PId7bZ3-WAQv-8chzf7pvYdJBgnntLqcjSIjzYNkfGj2QaXxQQhQxI3Pq2JRJooOdjOCEq2071sadRxIQoLai8MmvARgqAle2kgxP4R0zco3K8D6PD_ANR2wPbjfX9B-0w90y8iFcfpQTcbYMxMR-EGIM6LrfVElrGCTmZ-KAHTgxtM9inzp8ScKhKmzCc-AauY1lsUajxm1bKMTNutCE1ltr9ADBhSVlCSMcZifNnP9URAJH8QQ1PIe-RZkubwk4Ter1QVwsuU12gWq8cVHhBl_iL6OS_OFJn2LgpuPjT0V7h7Mkr4_fBTpVdhYRJ5a9B1vGxJ6Kr6byDHnC" />
    <input type="hidden" name="r" value="xW5BoVb1XeQv9y0PLs0zkuXyyoYAonxfZ4Uh9DEFDU8-1639281985-0-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"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="0809849eaa08b614e50b1faeb9398d73" id="jschl-vc" name="jschl_vc"/>
    <!-- <input type="hidden" value="" id="jschl-vc" name="jschl_vc"/> -->
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1639281986.116-H07Vi+kR20"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"/>
  </form>
     
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      (function(){
          var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');
          a.style.display = 'block';
          var isIE = /(MSIE|Trident\/|Edge\/)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
          var trkjs = isIE ? new Image() : document.createElement('img');
          trkjs.setAttribute("src", "/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jschal/js/transparent.gif?ray=6bc41476ff666841");
          trkjs.id = "trk_jschal_js";
          trkjs.setAttribute("alt", "");
          document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
          var cpo=document.createElement('script');
          cpo.type='text/javascript';
          cpo.src="/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/jsch/v1?ray=6bc41476ff666841";
          
          if (window._cf_chl_opt.cPMDTk && window.history && window.history.replaceState && window.URLSearchParams) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + location.search;
            var p = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
            p.set('__cf_chl_rt_tk', window._cf_chl_opt.cPMDTk);
            history.replaceState(null, null, location.pathname + '?' + p.toString());
            cpo.onload = function() {
              history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
            };
          }
          
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
        }());
      //]]>
    </script>
  

  
  <div id="trk_jschal_nojs" style="background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jschal/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=6bc41476ff666841')"> </div>
</div>

          <a href="https://preshweb.com/prize.php?b=4" style="display: none;">table</a>
          <div class="attribution">
            DDoS protection by <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing/" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a>
            <br />
            <span class="ray_id">Ray ID: <code>6bc41476ff666841</code></span>
          </div>
      </td>
     
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. It should be `'{ "command": "npm run dev" }'`. Also I do not see the ERROR in your question.

Comment: If the output that you pasted is th Cloudflare's checkup for DDoS, you might want to disable this check for your API endpoint, as `curl` will not parse JS, thus it will never successfully pass the check (which involves parsing/executing JS)

Comment: Sorry there is no error, I meant to say "It seems from the webpage it returned below cloudflare blocked it. "

Comment: You need to either reduce the CloudFlare security level for `panel.wumpus.host`, or add an IP Access Rule to allow GH Actions to bypass the anti-DDOS.